# Import local python file to Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I need to import a few python files stored in my local memory as modules in my Jupyter Notebook.

My jupyter notebook is store in C:\snip\Pictures\demo and I need to import python files stored in C:\snip\Pictures\demo\mrcnn.

When I try this:

```
from mrcnn import utils
from mrcnn import visualize
from mrcnn.visualize import display_images
from mrcnn.visualize import display_instances
import mrcnn.model as modellib
from mrcnn.model import log
from mrcnn.config import Config
from mrcnn import model as modellib, utils
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-fdc1339465a7> in <module>
     17 import matplotlib.image as mpimg
     18 
---> 19 from mrcnn import utils
     20 from mrcnn import visualize
     21 from mrcnn.visualize import display_images

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mrcnn'
```

mrcnn is the folder name, and utils, visualize... are python files within the folder. How do I solve this?

Comment: try `import mrcnn.utils`

Comment: Still get the same error

Comment: Add a file called `__init__.py` to the folder mrcnn. It can be empty

Comment: A python file with the same name already exists.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing works with using .py files, but Jupyter files are a bit different.  You need to import modules by adding %run 
If you wish to also use the variables in the py file, use %run -i.

Answer (score 1):

Do this. Print the `sys.path` like this. This lists the directories that the python interpreter is looking inside when doing `import`.

```
import sys

print(sys.path)
```

```
Output (Something like this):

['/mnt/c/Users/lapto/Desktop/demos', '/home/elaaf/anaconda3/lib/python38.zip', '/home/elaaf/anaconda3/lib/python3.8', '/home/elaaf/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/elaaf/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/home/elaaf/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/locket-0.2.1-py3.8.egg']
```

If your current working directory is in the output list.
Your `import` calls are not simply not looking in the current directory.

Try adding the current directory to the `sys.path` and importing the modules

```
import sys

sys.path.append(".")
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: My current directory is in the output list. This probably means it knows to look in the mrcnn folder right?

Comment: Yes. Also I tested your situation in a Jupyter notebook, it imported just fine. Strange.

Comment: Made a new notebook and it worked, no idea why. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This might be outdated. I came across this post as I have the same issue. And when I saw Vedant Modi's comment saying that "Made a new notebook and it worked, no idea why", it comes to me that it might works to try to restart the kernel. And yes, restart the kernel fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Jupyter notebooks from VS Code and I faced a similar challenge. I adopted this approach:

### Folder structure

I would like to explain my solution using the simplified folder structure shown below. I want to re-use the code in `mymodule.py` in my notebooks `mynotebook1.ipynb`

```
root
    |
    |----mynotebook1.ipynb
    |
    |
    |----mynotebook2.ipynb
    |
    |----modules
    |    |
    |    |-----__init__.py
    |    |
    |    |-----mymodule.py
    |
    |
```

### Content of mymodule.py

```py
class MyAlgorithms
     @staticmethod
    def some_implementation_1():
        print("Inside implmentation 1" )

     @staticmethod
    def some_implementation_2():
        print("Inside implmentation 2" )
```

### Content of **init**.py

```py
from modules.mymodule import MyAlgorithms


__all__=[MyAlgorithms]
```

### Referencing the code of mymodule.py in the notebooks

```
import modules
modules.MyAlgorithms.some_implementation_1()
```

### Advantages of this approach

- It lets me keep more complex code outside of the Jupyter notebook in well organized classes
- I get better GIT control and change tracking than that what I would have if all the code were in the notebook

### Disadvantages

- I have to re-start the Jupyter notebook when I make some changes to the code in the modules folder.